# Why can't I print out array of struct

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, data-structures, struct

```
struct Menu
{
    float id;
    char item[50];
    struct Menu* subMenu[10];
} Menu[5] = {
    {1, "SEARCH YOUR CONTACT", (struct Menu[]){{1.1, "ADD TO FAVOURITES"}, {1.2, "UPDATE"}, {1.3, "DELETE"}, {1.4, "ADD FIELD"}, {1.5, "BACK TO MAIN MENU"}}},
    {2, "ADD CONTACT"},
    {3, "DISPLAY FAVOURITES CONTACT", (struct Menu[]){{3.1, "ADD TO FAVOURITES"}, {3.2, "UPDATE"}, {3.3, "DELETE"}, {3.4, "ADD FIELD"}, {3.5, "BACK TO MAIN MENU"}}},
    {4, "DISPLAY ALL CONTACT", (struct Menu[]){{4.1, "ADD TO FAVOURITES"}, {4.2, "UPDATE"}, {4.3, "DELETE"}, {4.4, "ADD FIELD"}, {4.5, "BACK TO MAIN MENU"}}},
    {5, "EXIT APPLICATION"}
};
void menuItem()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf(" ... %.1f \\", Menu[0].subMenu[i]->id);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
... 1.1 \Error: segmention fault
```

I tried printing method

```
printf("%.1f", Menu[0].subMenu[1]->id);
```

but it didn't work.

I want to print out all elements of the array struct.

Comment: Your 2nd element ("ADD CONTACT") does not have any `subMenu` entries.

Comment: You declare `subMenu` as an array of *pointers*, but you initialize it with an array of structure *objects*.

Comment: @nomnom Where is the array of structures defined? In file scope or within a function?

Comment: On an unrelated note: Using a `float` as the id is probably not a good idea. What happens if you use an id that can't be represented exactly as a `float`? And how would you use sub-sub-menus if you can't have e.g. `1.1.1`?

Comment: Extending on @Someprogrammerdude : *All* of your ids `x.y` apart from `x.5` cannot be represented exactly as they are periodic in binary...

Comment: I find the data, at least as written, impossible to read.  You already got feedback on the id.  Fixed size item is odd, as is fixed size sub-menus.  Strings use a '\0' sentinel, you can use a special id, or have it hold and array of pointers to menus and use NULL to signify end of list.  I would probably model this as a flat array of `{ unsigned char level, char *item}` and let the position in the array be id.

Comment: @Allan Wind... My thoughts, kinda, when nomnom asked the previous question... Take a lesson from IP addresses. `192.168.4.3`... 32 bits with some very simple & primitive masking and it would be tough to fill it up...

Comment: @Fe2O3 Op deleted other question it seems.

Answer (score 2):

Others already pointed out the problem with `float id` so I suggest you use a menu and submenu indices instead (either as is, a struct, or as @Fe2O3 pointed out mapped into an integer like `unsigned id = m << 8 | sm`).  I made item a `char *` instead of fixed size and the sub-menu an array of pointers to Menu:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Menu {
    char *item;
    struct Menu **subMenu;
} Menu[] = {
    {"SEARCH YOUR CONTACT", (struct Menu *[]) {
        &(struct Menu) {"ADD TO FAVORITES"},
        &(struct Menu) {"UPDATE"},
        &(struct Menu) {"DELETE"},
        &(struct Menu) {"ADD FIELD"},
        &(struct Menu) {"BACK TO MAIN MENU"},
        NULL
    }},
    {"ADD CONTACT", NULL},
};

int main() {
    for (int m = 0; m < sizeof Menu / sizeof *Menu; m++) {
        printf("item: %s\n", Menu[m].item);
        for(int sm = 0;  Menu[m].subMenu && Menu[m].subMenu[sm]; sm++) {
            printf("  item: %s\n", Menu[m].subMenu[sm]->item);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the example output:

```
item: SEARCH YOUR CONTACT
  item: ADD TO FAVORITES
  item: UPDATE
  item: DELETE
  item: ADD FIELD
  item: BACK TO MAIN MENU
item: ADD CONTACT
```

Alternatively use a flat array and an `unsigned char` or enum to indicate the level:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Menu {
    unsigned char level;
    char *item;
} Menu[] = {
    {0, "SEARCH YOUR CONTACT"},
    {1, "ADD TO FAVORITES"},
    {1, "UPDATE"},
    {1, "DELETE"},
    {1, "ADD FIELD"},
    {1, "BACK TO MAIN MENU"},
    {0, "ADD CONTACT"},
};

int main() {
    for(int m = 0; m < sizeof Menu / sizeof *Menu; m++) {
        printf("%*s%sitem: %s\n", 2 * Menu[m].level, "", Menu[m].item);
    }
}
```